# Can smartphones connect to bluetooth mesh networks as nodes?

Tags: bluetooth, android, mesh-analysis

In an existing Bluetooth Mesh network where there are a few nodes that communicate with each other. Can an android smartphone connect to that network (where necessary) and be a part of such network as a node broadcasting some data to the other nodes?

Comment: If you programmed it to do so, then yes.

Comment: This is off topic, as it concerns only software protocols and not hardware capabilities

Comment: @ChrisStratton that's what I was looking for, to find out if it concerns hardware capabilities.